# GlusterFS and ZFS snapshots

Tags: zfs, glusterfs

I know many people are using GlusterFS on top on ZFS.

I'm wondering about snapshots: how do you ensure snapshot homogeneity among the nodes? I mean if you do a snapshot on a node, how can you be sure it will be the same on the other nodes so you can use zfs send/receive later?

Thanks in advance